# ghost works well except when I click on title of my blog

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

The blog's URL is https://linuxhowto.tech/

It works great except specifically when I click on the title of my blog then the URL goes to http://localhost:2368/

I've looked at docs and config files and I'm not sure what would fix this. Any ideas? I'm about one inch from getting this blog to work and I'm sort of excited about it actually.

Addendum. I think adding my config.js might help.

````
// # Ghost Configuration
// Setup your Ghost install for various [environments](http://support.ghost.org/config/#about-environments).

// Ghost runs in `development` mode by default. Full documentation can be found at http://support.ghost.org/config/

var path = require('path'),
    config;

config = {
    // ### Production
    // When running Ghost in the wild, use the production environment.
    // Configure your URL and mail settings here
    production: {
        url: 'https://linuxhowto.tech',
        mail: {},
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },

        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2368'
        }
    },

    // ### Development **(default)**
    development: {
        // The url to use when providing links to the site, E.g. in RSS and email.
        // Change this to your Ghost blog's published URL.
        url: 'https://linuxhowto.tech',

        // Example refferer policy
        // Visit https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/ for instructions
        // default 'origin-when-cross-origin',
        // referrerPolicy: 'origin-when-cross-origin',

        // Example mail config
        // Visit http://support.ghost.org/mail for instructions
        // ```
        //  mail: {
        //      transport: 'SMTP',
        //      options: {
        //          service: 'Mailgun',
        //          auth: {
        //              user: '', // mailgun username
        //              pass: ''  // mailgun password
        //          }
        //      }
        //  },
        // ```

        // #### Database
        // Ghost supports sqlite3 (default), MySQL & PostgreSQL
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-dev.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },
        // #### Server
        // Can be host & port (default), or socket
        server: {
            // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
            port: '2368'
        },
        // #### Paths
        // Specify where your content directory lives
        paths: {
            contentPath: path.join(__dirname, '/content/')
        }
    },

    // **Developers only need to edit below here**

    // ### Testing
    // Used when developing Ghost to run tests and check the health of Ghost
    // Uses a different port number
    testing: {
        url: 'https://linuxhowto.tech',
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-test.db')
            },
            pool: {
                afterCreate: function (conn, done) {
                    conn.run('PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;' +
                    'PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY;' +
                    'PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE;' +
                    'BEGIN EXCLUSIVE; COMMIT;', done);
                }
            },
            useNullAsDefault: true
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        },
        logging: false
    },

    // ### Testing MySQL
    // Used by Travis - Automated testing run through GitHub
    'testing-mysql': {
        url: 'https://linuxhowto.tech',
        database: {
            client: 'mysql',
            connection: {
                host     : '127.0.0.1',
                user     : 'root',
                password : '',
                database : 'ghost_testing',
                charset  : 'utf8'
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        },
        logging: false
    },

    // ### Testing pg
    // Used by Travis - Automated testing run through GitHub
    'testing-pg': {
        url: 'https://linuxhowto.tech',
        database: {
            client: 'pg',
            connection: {
                host     : '127.0.0.1',
                user     : 'postgres',
                password : '',
                database : 'ghost_testing',
                charset  : 'utf8'
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        },
        logging: false
    }
};

module.exports = config;
````

Answer (score 0):

If you're self hosting this is accomplished by editing the `url`-field  in the `config.js` file.

#### From the [user docs](http://support.ghost.org/config/#url):

> One of the first things you’ll need to do after installing a Ghost blog, is set the URL for your blog in `config.js`. This URL must match the URL you will use to access your blog, if it is not set correctly you may get the error Access Denied from url as well as finding that RSS and other external links do not work correctly.
>
> url should be set to the full URL for your blog including `http://` or if you are using SSL for your blog and want both the admin and frontend to always be served securely, use `https://`. See the section on SSL configuration for more information about how to configure your URL if you want to use SSL for just the admin or only for secure requests.
>
> If you want to Ghost to appear on a subpath or subdirectory of your domain, e.g. `http://my-ghost-blog.com/blog/` the full path needs to be specified in the url field. This option is only available when self-hosting Ghost.

If you're using the Ghost Pro service I would suggest to contact their support.

Comment: The blog seems to load fine when i just enter it in a browser https://linuxhowto.tech/

Comment: @NeilAnuskiewicz the fact that it loads just mean that you have the DNS and server set up correctly, not neccesarily the Ghost configuration.

Did you restart the server after making configuration changes?

Comment: I just restarted njinx to see if that would do the trick. No dice. The site is https://linuxhowto.tech/

BTW, I'm excited to have scored the perfect domain name for blog of howtos!! I can't wait to get started. This is the last problem and I can do a first post. Fun.

Comment: You need to restart the Ghost instance, not Nginx.

Comment: Ah, Okay, maybe that's the problem. I'll try it. I just added my config.js and the real domain name instead of config.js as there's nothing really secret here. It's just a blog.

Comment: That should do it. Also make sure to start in production mode.

Comment: Darn, i restarted ghost and no dice.

Comment: Make sure I start in production mode? What do you mean? I'll go look at the config.js but I thought I was already in production mode.

Comment: If you just run with `npm start` it will default to development mode. You need to add parameters such as `--production` for it to start in production mode. You can read more about it in the [official documentation](http://docs.ghost.org/pl/usage/configuration/#using-environments-)

Comment: I went ahead and ran npm start --production and still no dice. I even went and restarted both ghost and njinx just for good measure. This is such a weird problem.

Comment: Either it's a really complex problem or it's something really simple that you missed. I bet it's the latter but I don't think I can be of more help without more information.

Comment: I even tried NODE_ENV=production pm2 start index.js --name "Ghost" which I found in some other docs. I am thinking there's a config that's wrong somewhere. Do you see anything wrong with my config.js? Maybe I should just restart the server entirely or something. I know i'm getting tired when I start thinking like this is windows 98 or something. Just restart. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135754/discussion-between-reedyn-and-neil-anuskiewicz).